# Put method to AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, superclass, setcontentview

I have a problem by `calling` a method. I created a `button`, if I click on it, it start the `onClick()`. This method is calling to other methods from `up-class`. In these methods I set the `layout` by `setContentView(R.layout...);`to two different layouts. At the moment my code change the layout very fast to the second layout. How can I handle it, that the second layout will only set, if the first method is ready? I know it must be something with `asynch-tasks`, but I need help to handle it.

**My code:**

```
public void do(int a) {
 method1();
 method2();
 }
```

Both methods are from an superclass. Method1 should setContentView(r.layout.1) and method2 to r.layout.2.

Comment: Where exactly is your `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want some time between first and second method you can call second method after some delay using handler as below

```
public void do(int a) {
 method1();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{

        @Override
        public void run() 
                {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                method2();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                           Log.d("Exception",""+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        }, 500);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but is there any option to handle it more flexible without to set a time. It should first run the method1() and after that method2, method3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an AsyncTask:

```
public class BasicAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) { // this will start when .execute() is called
        method1();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {   // this will be executed when doInbackGround finishes
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        method2();
    }
}
```

to start AsynkTask:

```
BasicAsyncTask basicAsyncTask = new BasicAsyncTask();
basicAsyncTask.execute();
```